# How to register within a decorator all functions it decorates?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Say you have the following decorator. How can it be modified to say append to some list references to all the functions it decorates?

```
def memoize(obj):
    cache = obj.cache = {}

    @functools.wraps(obj)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[args]
    return memoizer

@memoize
def foo(bar):
    return bar ** 3
```

Comment: Do you care where "some list" is stored?  Do you want it to be a global variable or somehow attached to the decorator itself?

Comment: make it a class instead of a method... then use a static variable to append each obj to on the `__init__`

Comment: @BrenBarn No I don't really care where the list is stored.

Comment: To stay consistent you can provide a higher level decorator for your decorator that closes on a list, and store the decorated function references there.

Comment: @JoranBeasley and @ malfunctioning: I am a bit new with decorators so if you can provide a bit more detailed explanation of how your suggestions work in some answers I'd really appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily store a list on the decorator-function object (`memoize.decorated`):

```
_decorated = []

def memoize(obj):
    cache = obj.cache = {}

    # add to the decorated list
    _decorated.append(obj)

    @functools.wraps(obj)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[args]
    return memoizer

# make the list accessible from the decorator:
memoize.decorated = _decorated
```

It can be used like:

```
@memoize
def foo(bar):
    return bar ** 3

print memoize.decorated
```

As a side note, you should consider storing [`WeakRef`s in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/677978/2096752), to avoid memory leak or objects not getting freed when no other "real" references to them are left.

Comment: Using `__` at the beginning and ends of names is discouraged, since those are supposed to be only for Python internals.  There's no real reason to use even a leading `__` here.  (I'd say there isn't much reason to use even a single underscore, but that's more debatable.)

Comment: @BrenBarn agreed, I fixed naming